# In History's Unmarked Grave of Discarded Lies

Tags: meaning, metaphors, rhetoric

I have been trying to google the meaning of the above mentioned sentence which was spoken by the US President George Bush when he was addressing the joint-congress after 9/11 attack.

I'll just highlight the part which I am interested to know the meaning of :

> **We're not deceived by their pretenses to piety.**
>
> We have seen their kind before. They're the heirs of all the murderous ideologies of the 20th century. By sacrificing human life to serve their radical visions, by abandoning every value except the will to power, they follow in the path of fascism, Nazism and totalitarianism. And they will follow that path all the way to where it ends **in history's unmarked grave of discarded lies.**

Comment: You can't google huge, long sentences and expect to find them. You have to parse a sentence into component parts. History has a grave where discarded lies are buried and the graves are not marked. That should do you.

Answer (score 1):

> We're not deceived by their pretenses to piety.

Bush is referring to a group of people who are *pretending to be pious*, or put up a *false pretense* of being pious. He's saying, "We see that you're pretending to be pious and we're not deceived by it".

> ...in history's unmarked grave of discarded lies

Continuing on the theme of lies, pretense, and deception, Bush is creating a metaphor here to describe where such lies will go—into an unmarked grave with other such lies. He's essentially saying "your deception won't work on us, and we'll put your deception in its grave".

From a political standpoint, Bush is trying to show himself to be honest and patriotic by calling out deception and decrying the state's enemies.

Answer (score 0):

The quotes come from a speech that President George Bush gave to a joint session of Congress on 21 September 2001 following the attacks ten days earlier that damaged the Pentagon and destroyed the twin towers of the World Trade Centre in New York.

His declared target was "a radical network of terrorists" on whom he declared war, beginning with Al Qaeda. Bush condemned the ideology that motivated Al Qaeda and groups sympathetic to it. He declared - in the lines you quote - that, in their murderous drive to achieve power, these people acted in the same manner as the world's worst totalitarian regimes had done. And, in the line in **bold** type, he declares that Al Qaeda and its fellow travellers will fail too, suffering the same fate as similar tyrannical regimes (with specific reference to the Axis powers in WWII.)

The President uses an elaborate metaphor to describe this fate - saying they and their false teachings (their **discarded lies**) will inevitably end up lost to the world and forgotten like a skeleton buried in an unmarked grave.

**Their pretences to piety** refers to the religious fervour that partly inspires radical Islamic groups such as Al Qaeda. Bush regards this fervour as simulated rather than truly pious, a pretence intended to further the group's ends.

https://sourcebooks.fordham.edu/mod/2001Bush-speech-sep212001-onWTC.asp